# VBA instr Function used in Left function?

Tags: vba, excel

What I Have:

A column I have this data 24/25,25/26, up to 100/101 and in B column I have this data 24,25,26, up to 101. Using Left function I'm checking Left(24/25,2) with column B.... when coming to 100/101 it's giving me return as 10.

What I want:

Left(100/101,2) Then its have return 100 how do I do that I know if we give 3 then it will return but when we give three then 24/ also come. Give me any Suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Sheet formula version:**

You want to Find the position of "/" in the cell, then remove 1. That will give the number of characters before the "/" that you are after for Left. So, if data was in A2, you would put the following in B2:

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1),"")
```

---

**A VBA version (User defined function) might look like:**

As you mention using `Instr`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()

 Debug.Print GetLeft([A2].Text)
End Sub

Public Function GetLeft(ByVal aString As String) As Variant
    If InStr(aString, "/") > 0 Then
        GetLeft = Left$(aString, InStr(aString, "/") - 1)
    Else
        GetLeft = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Split Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/split-function):

```
Dim str As String
str = "24/25,25/26"

Dim arr As Variant
arr = Split(str, "/")
```

The result then is

```
'arr(0) is "24"
'arr(1) is "25,25"
'arr(2) is "26"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Like`.

```
If Range("A4").Value2 & "/" Like "*" & range("B4").Value2 & "/*" Then
```

I added a "/" at the right of each side, to avoid 10 matching 100 or 101.

Comment: How do I use <= and > operators there?